# Unable to use read-only mode in emacs v 17.2

Tags: emacs, readonly

I like opening file in read-only mode but v17.2 failed with this error:

> emacs test --eval (setq buffer-read-only t)'
> Unmatched '.

open a file in read-only mode and I expected the file to be opened in emacs.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Emacs 17.2? GNU Emacs? (It looks like the error msg is saying that you have an unmatched single-quote character.)

Comment: GNU Emacs 17.2 would be approximately 38 years old :)  Clarification needed... (I'd assume it was a typo for 27.2, but it would have to be a typo which was made twice in 5 lines of text without being noticed.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this due to the lack of clarity or follow-up, but... the quoted command suggests to me that the error is merely on account of a failure to quote the argument for the eval option.